# OpenType support missing for "Ubuntu", script 20 - pyside6-designer

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

The Qt Designer app is launched without any issue. However, when I click on a widget, layout option, or any other option in the app, an error appears in the terminal and closes the Qt Designer window. I am using ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.9.16

```
pyside6-designer
Error: ERROR: ld.so: object 'libpython3.9.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
  OpenType support missing for "Ubuntu", script 20
  OpenType support missing for "Ubuntu", script 20
```

I am trying to find a solution for this error.